# Is there a GetOrgChart Angular component with Express RESTful APIs

Tags: angular, rest, getorgchart

Is there a `GetOrgChart` Angular component?
We want to use it for an Angular 4+ project with RESTful APIs generated by Express.

Comment: There is no GetOrgChart wrapper for Angular